# Why the output is 18 of this static function?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int f(int n)
{
    static int r = 0;
    if (n <= 0) return 1;
    if (n > 3)
    {
        r = n;
        return f(n-2)+2;
    }
    return f(n-1)+r;
}
 
int main()
{
    printf("%d", f(5));
}
```

How to solve this one? I have used static variable r and initialized to zero. And calling the function from main. The output I am getting is 18.

Comment: why did you tag several programming languages? Please only tag the relevant one.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: What is that function supposed to do?

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to [edit] your question to improve them.

Comment: 1 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 2 is 18, but why is that of any interest? If you want to see how the function works, you probably should step through it with a debugger. If you want to know what the function's purpose is, you should ask whoever wrote it (or read any documentation that came with the function).

Comment: How its calling and adding itself till 18 without loop please explain. I have read documentation but this is different. This was the exam ques thats why its important for me

Comment: You might want to do a little more research about *recursion*. Which is (in a way) just a fancy loop.

Answer (score 3):

```
 1| #include <stdio.h>
 2| int f(int n)
 3| {
 4|     static int r = 0;
 5|     if (n <= 0) return 1;
 6|     if (n > 3)
 7|     {
 8|         r = n;
 9|         return f(n-2)+2;
10|     }
11|     return f(n-1)+r;
12| }

int main()
{
    printf("%d", f(5));
}
```

- When you call `f(5)`, the function sets `r=5` and returns at l.9 : `f(3)+2`
- When you call `f(3)`, the function returns at l.11: `f(2)+5`
- When you call `f(2)`, the function returns at l.11: `f(1)+5`
- When you call `f(1)`, the function returns at l.11: `f(0)+5`
- When you call `f(0)`, the function returns at l.5 : `1`

Therefore:

- `f(1)` is `1+5`
- `f(2)` is `1+5+5`
- `f(3)` is `1+5+5+5`
- `f(5)` is `1+5+5+5+2` => `18`